# Can't ignore Content Description on new app

Tags: android, accessibility

I have developed two other apps and was able to drop the Content Description when they run.  However, a new app I am working on will not drop it.

```
android:contentDescription="@null"
android:importantForAccessibility="no"
tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
```

I've tried the above in all combinations, and Content Description still showing.